# PIP Rediscluster ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redis._compat'

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I am recently having problems with installing rediscluster. When I run `pip install rediscluster`, it runs it fine, but after a second, it just shows error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redis._compat'`. I have tried running `pip install rediscompat, pip install redis.compat, pip install redis._compat and pip install redis_compat`, but none of them worked. Anyone know how to get `redis._compat`?

I appreciate any help! Thanks

**I tried running these commands:**

`pip install rediscompat, pip install redis.compat, pip install redis.\_compat and pip install redis_compat`

**And this was the result:**

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redis._compat'`

**And I expected this:**

(not actually the result, but this is what I expected to happen) `Successfully installed rediscluster` and many other modules. I have not seen the result, but I atleast think that this would be the result.

Comment: https://github.com/redis/redis-py/issues/1718#issuecomment-971316393

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and fixed it by running

```
pip install redis-py-cluster
```

instead. :)